# How can I parse a date including timezone with Joda Time

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

This snippet of code always parses the date into the current timezone, and not into the timezone in the string being parsed.

```
final DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat
        .forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy");
final DateTime dateTime = df
        .parseDateTime("Mon Aug 24 12:36:46 GMT+1000 2009");
System.out.println("dateTime = " + dateTime);
// outputs dateTime = 2009-08-24T04:36:46.000+02:00
```

It outputs:

```
dateTime = 2009-08-24T04:36:46.000+02:00
```

whereas I expect:

```
dateTime = 2009-08-24T04:36:46.000+10:00
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

OK, further Googling gave me the answer to my own question: use [`withOffsetParsed()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withOffsetParsed%28%29), as so:

```
final DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat
        .forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy");
final DateTime dateTime = df.withOffsetParsed()
        .parseDateTime("Mon Aug 24 12:36:46 GMT+1000 2009");
```

This works.

Comment: IMO, the default behavior of `DateTimeFormatter` seems to violate "principle of least astonishment", especially in the context of an unmarshaller. Thank you Steve for unearthing `withOffsetParsed()`.

Comment: I have to agree that the default behaviour - i.e. ignoring a properly parsed timezone - is bizarre.

Answer (score 38):

also you can chose:

```
// parse using the Paris zone
DateTime date = formatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Paris")).parseDateTime(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

### Do not use a fixed text for the timezone:

Do not use a fixed text (e.g. `'GMT'`) for the timezone as you have done because that approach may fail for other locales.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Mon Aug 24 12:36:46 GMT+1000 2009";
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d H:m:s VVZ u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, parser);
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Custom fromat
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(odt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2009-08-24T12:36:46+10:00
2009-08-24T12:36:46.000+10:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/nFRecg)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: I prefer `'GMT'Z`. `GMT+1000` are not two pieces of information, `GMT` and `+1000` (which would have contradicted each other), but one piece. When we cannot parse as one piece, I prefer only to parse the bit that holds relevant information, that is `+1000`.  If one day (however unlikely) someone parsed into a `ZonedDateTime` using your formatter, they would get a result that was 10 hours off. Your `VV` will tell the reader that `GMT` is the zone ID of the date and time, which is not the case, so it will confuse rather than help.

Comment: @OleV.V. - "If one day (however unlikely) someone parsed into a ZonedDateTime using your formatter, they would get a result that was 10 hours off."  - This is not correct. `System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, parser))` gives `2009-08-24T02:36:46Z[GMT]` which represents the same instant/moment in time i.e. `2009-08-24T12:36:46+10:00` = `2009-08-24T02:36:46Z[GMT]`.

Comment: Your code holds even more surprises than I had thought. While you get the correct instant, you don’t get the expected time of day nor the expected zone. (And on Java 8 I got `2009-08-24T12:36:46Z[GMT]`, may be a bug in Java 8.)

Comment: It must be a bug in Java 8. Ideone server currently uses Java-12 and [here](https://ideone.com/CKAvgA) are the results on it.