# parse this type of date format in java?

Tags: java, date, date-parsing

what would be the easiest way to parse this date format below in java?:

```
2010-09-18T10:00:00.000+01:00
```

i read the DateFormat api in java and could not find a method that takes a string or even this type of date format as a paremeter to parse? When i mean by parse i mean i want to extract the "date (day month and year)", "time" and "timezone" into seperate string objects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're looking for a regex or similar answer.  I provided a second answer with a specific, working regex for this specific solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another answer, since you seem to be focused on simply tearing the `String` apart (not a good idea, IMHO.)  Let's assume the string is valid ISO8601.  Can you assume it will *always* be in the form you cite, or is it just valid 8601?  If the latter, you have to cope with a bunch of scenarios as [these guys did](http://www.pelagodesign.com/blog/2009/05/20/iso-8601-date-validation-that-doesnt-suck/).

The regex they came up with to validate 8601 alternatives is:

```
^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])
 (-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])
 ((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?
 ([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$
```

Figuring out how to tease out the correct capture groups makes me woozy.  Nevertheless, the following will work for your specific case:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Regex8601
{
  static final Pattern r8601 = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})T((\\d{2}):"+
                               "(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})\\.(\\d{3}))((\\+|-)(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}))");


  //2010-09-18T10:00:00.000+01:00

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String thisdate = "2010-09-18T10:00:00.000+01:00";
    Matcher m = r8601.matcher(thisdate);
    if (m.lookingAt()) {
      System.out.println("Year: "+m.group(1));
      System.out.println("Month: "+m.group(2));
      System.out.println("Day: "+m.group(3));
      System.out.println("Time: "+m.group(4));
      System.out.println("Timezone: "+m.group(9));
    } else {
      System.out.println("no match");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i make a call to a web service that sends me a calendar event date in 8601 format and then want me to show the time, date and timezone seperately. a pain i know as why couldnt they blooming do this from their own side if this is how they want to display the information

Comment: Also: i was working on a reg ex myself using these:

private static final String REG_EX_DATE = "(.*)T";
 private static final String REG_EX_TIME = "T(.*)+";
 private static final String REG_EX_TIMEZONE = "+|-(.*)";

Comment: im going to try the above code anyway cheers for that

Comment: Nope, code above diddnt work. you can try it here if you like:

http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

i will try the first reg ex you posted

Comment: I don't know anything about that regexplant thing.  The code above compiled and ran fine on my JDK, giving me Year: 2010
Month: 09
Day: 18
Time: 10:00:00.000
Timezone: 01:00

Comment: And in any case, I suggest using a `SimpleDateFormat` and a Calendar (or the JodaTime equivalent) to extract the relevant bits.

Comment: @jonney: If the above code didn't work, can you please show me the output you saw?

Comment: Hi, i got it to work somehow. ran it on my machine one more time and it worked. i am able to parse the date using the first reg ex you posted taken from that website

Comment: Go with the link which explains how "those guys did it".

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing anything non-trivial with dates and times, recommend the use of [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).  See [this extensive SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709870/how-do-libraries-in-different-programming-languages-handle-date-time-timestamp), including [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  See also ["Should I use native data/time..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589870/should-i-use-java-date-and-time-classes-or-go-with-a-3rd-party-library-like-joda).

Here's an example code snippet, taken from [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/ISO8601dateparsingutility.htm), if you want to use JDK `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
// 2004-06-14T19:GMT20:30Z
// 2004-06-20T06:GMT22:01Z

// http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html
//    
// http://www.intertwingly.net/wiki/pie/DateTime
//
// http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime
//
// Different standards may need different levels of granularity in the date and
// time, so this profile defines six levels. Standards that reference this
// profile should specify one or more of these granularities. If a given
// standard allows more than one granularity, it should specify the meaning of
// the dates and times with reduced precision, for example, the result of
// comparing two dates with different precisions.

// The formats are as follows. Exactly the components shown here must be
// present, with exactly this punctuation. Note that the "T" appears literally
// in the string, to indicate the beginning of the time element, as specified in
// ISO 8601.

//    Year:
//       YYYY (eg 1997)
//    Year and month:
//       YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)
//    Complete date:
//       YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)
//    Complete date plus hours and minutes:
//       YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00)
//    Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
//       YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
//    Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a
// second
//       YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)

// where:

//      YYYY = four-digit year
//      MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
//      DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
//      hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
//      mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
//      ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
//      s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
//      TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
public static Date parse( String input ) throws java.text.ParseException 
{
  //NOTE: SimpleDateFormat uses GMT[-+]hh:mm for the TZ which breaks
  //things a bit.  Before we go on we have to repair this.
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz" );

  //this is zero time so we need to add that TZ indicator for 
  if ( input.endsWith( "Z" ) ) {
    input = input.substring( 0, input.length() - 1) + "GMT-00:00";
  } else {
    int inset = 6;

    String s0 = input.substring( 0, input.length() - inset );
    String s1 = input.substring( input.length() - inset, input.length() );    

    input = s0 + "GMT" + s1;
  }

  return df.parse( input );        
}
```

Comment: You don't have to insert GMT before timezone. You just need `XXX` instead of `z` in the format string.

Answer (score 2):

This date is in [ISO 8601 format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). Here's [a link to a parser specific to this format](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/ISO8601dateparsingutility.htm) that uses the Java SimpleDateFormat parsing APIs internally.

Comment: Hi i think i diddnt explain myself properly. i get a string with the same format as the one i posted. what i want to do is to seperate the string into "date (year, month, and day)", "time" and "timezone".

Comment: Once you call parse() on the aforementioned API you will have a Java java.util.Date object. This should be enough for you to figure out how to do what you want. You'll also need to review the Java java.util.Calendar class API.

Comment: @jonney -- in this case you *could* separate the string using either a regex or simply string slices.  But that would be very brittle.  I think using a calendar implementation will treat you much better.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html),

Find examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.text/newSimpleDateFormatddMMMyyyyhhmmsszzz.htm) and [here](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), with the pattern as `yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

---

**Update** SimpleDateFormat won't work with ISO 8601 date format. Rather use, [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead. It provides [ISOChronology](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/chrono/ISOChronology.html) that complies with ISO 8601.

Brief example can be found on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327229/how-can-i-parse-a-date-including-timezone-with-joda-time).

Comment: That won't work. SimpleDateFormat uses RFC 822 to format time zones, while the example has a time zone String according to ISO 8601. These are not compatible.

Comment: Why is "SimpleDateFormat won't work with ISO 8601 date format"? Watch my answer, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Vladimir Prudnikov, your formatter won't take the timezone difference into consideration. How do you parse the `+01:00` at the end of the date format?

Comment: @Buhake Sindi What do you mean? Take a look at the code, I executed it and it parsed "2010-09-18T10:00:00.000+01:00" into "Sat Sep 18 11:00:00 CEST 2010", there is a timezone +01:00 and resulting hour value becomes 11, not 10. As for me everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory#newXMLGregorianCalendar(String lexicalRepresentation)` ([API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html)). The returned XMLGregorianCalendar gives you access to all the separate fields.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is this:

```
Date date = null;
SimpleDateFormat isoFormatWithMillis = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
try {
    date = isoFormatWithMillis.parse("2010-09-18T10:00:00.000+01:00");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(date);
```

This will print `Sat Sep 18 11:00:00 CEST 2010`.

Answer (score 0):

If  you are using Java 7 or earlier you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date).

If you are using Java 8 you could do:

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
    TemporalAccessor accessor = timeFormatter.parse("2015-10-27T16:22:27.605-07:00");

    Date date = Date.from(Instant.from(accessor));
    System.out.println(date);
```